# Append single quotes at starting and ending of the alphanumeric in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that has a SQL query, that is passed a alphanumeric number like `9760750B1CC37`.

My query is like

```
Select * from emp where emp_desc = {Parameter}
```

Now my issue here is emp_desc is a nchar field and when I pass the `9760750B1CC37` without `''` query returns no records but I can't pass the value as `'9760750B1CC37'` from crystal reports.

How can I convert the input `9760750B1CC37` to `'9760750B1CC37'` in query where clause?

My input is `9760750B1CC37` when it comes to query it should be

```
Select * from emp where emp_desc = '9760750B1CC37'
```

Not sure how to do it, either to concatenate the single quotes.

Comment: did you try to do something like `emp_desc = '{Parameter}'`

Comment: @hotfix that doesn't work as `{Parameter}` this whole part will be considered as string

Comment: @hotfix to my surprise your suggestion did work, Thanks for the great catch. Please add as answer will accept it

Comment: When you created the parameter in Crystal - set the parameter type as a string unless it's dynamic.  Maybe you tried this already and that is why you said it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your parameter is a string, you need to enclose references to it within the Command inside single quotes.

so just try instead of `{Parameter}` => `'{Parameter}'`

so your sql will looks like:

```
Select * from emp where emp_desc = '{Parameter}'
```